# Massive battery drain after factory restore

Tags: battery, youtube

I've been struggling the last couple of days figuring out a way to solve my mass battery drain issues on my android phone (Samsung Trend Android v 4.2.2). Since my time for finding a solution was running out (I used diagnostics tools to check wakeloks, battery usage and such, trying to turn off location services, etc. i mean i did try stuff) I decided to go with a full factory restoration.

Now the thing is I did this while specifying NOT to sync previous settings nor downloading my apps from my google accounts...I just wanted to see how it would behave "clean".

Seems like web browsing hasn't drained my battery (which it used to) but youtube persists on killing my style and decides to suck off my battery's soul after just a couple of videos (while fully charged).

I looked online and did search through out the forums but coudn't find a clue about this....anyone? help? please? lol.

Answer (score 0):

How old is the phone? It sounds like the battery is getting on in age, which typically leads to rapid battery life loss under heavy load.
Greenify helped me squeeze extra battery life out of my phone, it may help you too. Keep doing tests on how quickly is loses charge in different apps. Try using MX Player or your web browser to play the youtube video instead of the youtube app. The only other suggestion I have for increasing battery life would be switching to a custom ROM more suited for battery life preservation. Anything else either consider replacing the battery, or getting a 2nd external backup battery/case